# Pip Not Working On Raspberry Pi For Discord Bot

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

I wanted to run a discord bot from my raspberry pi so I could have it always running, so I transferred over the bot file.  BTW this bot was made in python.  I get an error saying `no module named discord`.  This is because I don't have discord installed.  Whenever I try to use `pip3 install discord` I get a message saying that it was successful, but was installed under Python 3.4.  I need it to be installed under Python 3.5 so that my bot's code will run properly.  If I try to use `python3 -m pip install discord` I get the error `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip`.  When I run `pip -V` I get 3.4. I want to make the version 3.5 instead of 3.4, but even after running the get-pip.py file I still am on pip 3.4.  Any help?

Comment: I think you're getting python and pip confused... You probably need to update python rather than pip.

Comment: First you will need to install pip for python3.5 version then using that pip install discord `module`

Comment: When I try to install pip from the get-pip.py file using Python 3.5 I get an ssl error saying that it couldn't fetch pip because it couldn't confirm the ssl.

Comment: And when I try to use `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` it gives me this: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`.  But I want pip to be installed in Python 3.5.  I know I have Python 3.5 installed because when I run `python3 -v` I get Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem on a different machine. what I did to have the python 3.6 interpreter as the default one for the python 3 command was this:

First, edit your .bashrc file to include the following line `export PATH=/path/to/python/bin:$PATH`(in this case, I will be using /home/pi/python). Then, download the python 3.6 using`wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz`. Unarchive it using `tar -zxvf Python-3.6.3.tgz`, and cding into the directory. Then, configure it by doing `./configure --prefix=$HOME/python`(Or to the path you had used in .bashrc), and make it using `make`, and `sudo make install`. Afterwards, reboot the raspberry pi, and you should now be able to use python 3.6 with the python3 command